# The document "Main.Storyboard" could not be opened. Unrecognized file content

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode8

I cannot open my Storyboard after updating from Xcode 7 to Xcode 8. 
Can anyone help? Inside it did not show any error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just find a solution as below:

Make sure the storyboard extension should start from lower case s.
Ex: it should be "Test.storyboard" not "Test.Storyboard"

Answer (score 62):

For me opening the storyboard as "Source code", fixing merge conflicts and then also restarting Xcode did the job.

Comment: Restarting did it for me. I had opened the storyboard in interface builder fine, then opened as source code to remove plain styling from navigation items, and then it wouldn't let me open in interface builder even after git resetting that file to the previous state.  All it took was an xcode restart.

Comment: It worked when restarting Xcode! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Restarting did it for me as well! You have no idea how grateful I am :))

Answer (score 9):

Just restarting XCode worked for me.

Thanks, XCode.