# The document “Main.Storyboard” could not be opened. Unrecognized file content in Xcode 8

Tags: xcode8

The Story board is not opening as an interface builder.Please tell me any solution.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you add the screen shot?

Comment: change Main.storyboard."s" is lower case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760818/the-document-main-storyboard-could-not-be-opened-unrecognized-file-content

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked was to create a new storyboard file, open the old and the new storyboards as source code (right click -> open as), and copy the xml from the old to the new storyboard. I didn't take the whole xml, just the scope of the `<scenes> </scenes>`